Is there an equivalent to the Shadow Weave in Eberron?
Faerun has the Shadow Weave, an alternative source for magic created by Shar (IIRC).
Does Eberron have an equivalent? I'm trying to determine whether the Shadow Weave Magic feat chain would be valid for an Eberron character without DM fiat.

No, but maybe yes?
Nothing is detailed anywhere in Eberron that is similar. Eberron doesn’t have a Weave (or at least nothing like it is described), and so there’s nothing to cast this particular Shadow.
But one of the core precepts of Eberron is

Ten Things You Need to Know
Every Dungeon Master and player needs to know and remember these facts about Eberron.

If it exists in D&D, then it has a place in Eberron. […]


(Eberron Campaign Setting, pg. 8; emphasis theirs)
This is the very first book that introduced Eberron to the world, and this is the very first “Thing You Need to Know” on the second page of actual text in the book.
So I don’t know how Shadow Weave Magic would work in Eberron. Nothing like it is described anywhere in the setting. But the authors state right up front, in bold text, before much of anything else, that it—and everything else—is supposed to have a place.
Furthermore, Tome of Magic—which is not a Realms-specific book—discusses the Shadow Weave some in its Shadow Magic chapter:

In the Forgotten Realms campaign setting, […] those few who truly understand it, such as shadow magic casters, use the Shadow Weave as the source for their power, drawing on it the way shadow mages of other worlds draw directly from the Plane of Shadow.

(Tome of Magic, pg. 110)
This statement is that Realms spellcasters use the Shadow Weave for things that use the Plane of Shadow elsewhere. That implies—sort of—that those elsewhere use the Plane of Shadow for things that Realms mages use the Shadow Weave. Thus, in theory, the Shadow Weave Magic feat in Eberron would imply someone who uses the Plane of Shadow—somehow—to get those bonuses to saving throws and caster level (and this somehow also reduces your spellcasting ability with other spells).
You’ll still need DM fiat to confirm this—the implication is weak, not to mention that Tome of Magic has questionable authority on anything about the Realms or about Eberron. And anyway, there’s still a lot of details to be sorted out—how does one tap into the Plane of Shadow to have these effects? Maybe it’s the result of secret rites associated with the Shadow, or the Dark Six as a whole, or the Dreaming Dark, to retain the deific connection (though none of these deities has remotely the influence on Eberron that Shar does on the Realms). Maybe it’s associated with Mabar, the Endless Night, one of Eberron’s  13  12 moons, or with the Nightbringer druids who worship it. Or one of the many things locked down in Khyber, daelkyr or rakshasa or Khyber, itself. Or maybe it’s none of those things, and just a quirky way of doing magic. Tome of Magic’s chapter on shadow magic introduces the Tenebrous Cabal, “a powerful organization governing the practice of shadow magic.” The book’s adaptation to the Forgotten Realms has the Cabal deal with the Shadow Weave. In Eberron, it becomes faction within Aundair’s Arcane Congress—though personally, I would prefer to put that faction within The Twelve, instead, to maintain its quasi-governmental role and make it apply beyond Aundair’s borders.
Anyway, that kind of thing will be up to the DM. But the option of taking the feat, that has pretty strong—though non-specific—textual support within Eberron’s rules.

I think  you're interpreting that line a little too broadly. Yes, a campaign setting is generally compatible with the game it's designed for - but that's the thing. Eberron is a campaign setting, a world with its own unique flavour, features, and locations, and the Forgotten Realms is a different campaign setting. Surely it's absurd to say that everything in Toril is also found in Eberron when neither setting can be found on the other's world map.

(Admittedly, the Spelljammer and Planescape campaign settings do both provide means to travel between Eberron and Toril, but they also provided rules that explain how the shadow weave appears present on one but not the other. Unfortunately, those rules didn't make it in to 3.5rd edition.)

@GMJoe The Shadow Weave itself? Perhaps so. The Shadow Weave Magic feat? That I think pretty clearly should be possible to take somehow. After all, Eberron certainly has shadow magic of various forms, such as Illusion (Shadow) spells and Tome of Magic mysteries.

@KRyan You're assuming there's a connection between the shadow subschool and the shadow weave, rather than just a coincidence of names. The shadow subschool is (according it its description in the PHB) so named because it interacts with the plane of shadow; the shadow weave is so named because it exists in the shadow of the weave. The etymologies are unrelated. (I'm not familiar with the Tome of Magic, though, so maybe there's something there? Does it mention elements of either campaign setting?)

@GMJoe No, Tome of Magic states that connection for me. Added a quote from there to this.
